# Run Excel Macro from external VBScript Error

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have two files.

1. example.wsf: an automation script
2. example.xlsm: an excel template with Macro, the Macro contains a API call to external server to retrieve data.

I am trying to call the Macro inside the example.wsf.

The example.wsf code:

```
<package>

  <job id="example">
    <script language="vbscript">

        Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

        Set objExcel = objApp.Workbooks.Open("example.xlsm",0,FALSE)    
        objApp.Visible = True
        objApp.DisplayAlerts = False

        objApp.Run("RefreshData")   

        msgbox "closing"

        objExcel.Close
        objApp.Quit

        Set objExcel = Nothing
        Set objApp = Nothing

        set objShell = Nothing

    </script>
  </job>

</package>
```

The Excel Macro code in example.xlsm:

```
Public Sub RefreshData()
  Dim API As New EXTERNAL_API
  Dim varResult As Variant
  Dim vSheet As String
  Dim LastRow, LastCol, vResult
  vSheet = "D"

  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(vSheet).Select
  Range("A6").Select
  Selection.Copy
  Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
  LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(vSheet).Cells(8, 1).End(xlDown).Row
  LastCol = 18

  API.ActivateAPI
  varResult = API.RunApplication("OfficeAPI", "application=excel,method=RefreshAll")
  MsgBox (varResult)

End Sub
```

The Macro itself is working well if it is triggered inside the Excel workbook.

But when the Macro is called from the VBScript, the EXTERNAL_API fail to execute, i.e., the following line does not execute:

```
varResult = API.RunApplication("OfficeAPI", "application=excel,method=RefreshAll")
```

I am suspecting that this may be related to early binding but basically have no clue what went wrong.

Comment: If the macro requires an Excel add-in to be loaded, you need to do that explicitly in the code. When you automate Excel like this you won't get any of its add-ins loaded by default.

Comment: @Rory Hi Rory, if I have added the add-in via excel option, do I need to explicitly load the add-in in the code?

Comment: Yes - if it's an .xla/.xlam the simplest way is to toggle the `.Installed` property of the `AddIn` object after opening your workbook.

Comment: @Rory Thank you! The add-in is actually a dll file. I have been searching quite some time. How can I explicitly load it in vba?

Comment: @Rory I think the problem is not due to add-ins since I found out the add-ins are the same when the macro is automated by a VBScript.

Comment: Is it a COM add-in then? Or do you have `Declare Function` statements, or a reference set to the dll?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are almost there.  Just some formatting issues. See the snippet below. Notice my comments about the file path and where the macro is located within the excel file.  Let me know if it works for you.

```
Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objExcel = objApp.Workbooks.Open("example.xlsm", 0, False) ''make sure you have valid path, such as a full UNC path
objApp.Visible = True
objApp.DisplayAlerts = False
objApp.Run "example.xlsm!RefreshData" ' this is if the Macro is in a Module.  Use "example.xlsm!sheet1.RefreshData" if it's on 
                                      '  sheet1, for example
```

Comment: Thank you Edward. The code above is able to call the Macro so I don't think it is the problem with the path. The problem is that when the Macro is called, the 'varResult = API.RunApplication("OfficeAPI", "application=excel,method=RefreshAll")' does not execute. Have you encountered this before?

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant RefreshData when you said external application.  Apologies, I cannot see why that line doesn't work when called from the script.  I think I would need to know more about the application.  Is it within the same workbook?

Comment: EXTRENAL_API is an api provided by a data feed application on my PC. That line works fine if I run the macro inside Excel but it will fail to retrieve any data if the macro is called by the vbscript in example.wsf. The behavior is very strange and I am thinking whether it's related to early binding.